# How to interpret "as of" in "violent or brutal acts as of thugs"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-meaning

Definition of "thuggery" @ vocabulary.com: violent or brutal acts as of thugs.

"as" is a preposition? "of" is a preposition? What does "as of" mean?

thanks.

Comment: As = like.  like that of thugs

Comment: @Jim like *those* of thugs.

Comment: *violent or brutal acts **as of** thugs* = *violent or brutal acts **such as those [acts] committed by** thugs*

Answer (score 1):

*violent or brutal acts as of thugs* is an abbreviated sentence. All dictionaries use the same or similar system to save space.

The full version would be:

Thuggery. This word refers to violent or brutal acts that are performed in the manner of thugs. (Or in the manner in which thugs perform them.)

You will see that "**as**" is an adverb, and **of** is a preposition.

Comment: Greybeard, I am not sure that is how to understand the lexicographical 'as of'.  My understanding, for what it is worth is that the dictionary is giving usage and that the preposition applies to that.  We use the word 'thuggery' 'of' <thugs>.  'Of' is regularly used in this way meaning 'applied to'.  So I would take the ellipse to be of 'used' so:  "violent or brutal acts as <used> of thugs.  Over time, whether Greybeard's or mine is the 'correct' understanding is probably out of reach.

Comment: @Tuffy As – in the manner (or state): *I see the colour as red. I bought it as seen*; Of – associated with – *The key of the door; the index of the book.*

Answer (score 0):

> violent or brutal acts as of thugs

This is a much abbreviated expression. There are various ways to expand it. My suggestion is:

*violent or brutal acts [such] as [those that are characteristic] of thugs*